# What is meaning of parameter in URL Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm doing with Webkit Browser on Android. I want get a sign red "A" in URL following:

> https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=vi&geocode=&q=7+Nguy%E1%BB%85n+Ch%C3%AD+Thanh,+T%C3%A2n+Th%E1%BA%A1nh,+Tam+K%E1%BB%B3,+Qu%E1%BA%A3ng+Nam,+Vi%E1%BB%87t+Nam&aq=0&oq=7+Nguy%E1%BB%85n+Ch%C3%AD+Thanh,+T%C3%A2n+Th%E1%BA%A1nh,+Tam+K%E1%BB%B3&sll=15.579176,108.470603&sspn=0.001573,0.002411&vpsrc=6&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=7+Nguy%E1%BB%85n+Ch%C3%AD+Thanh,+Tam+K%E1%BB%B3,+Qu%E1%BA%A3ng+Nam,+Vi%E1%BB%87t+Nam&ll=15.578003,108.471826&spn=0.006294,0.009645&t=m&z=17&ei=mwSGUKXwOK2tiQeHlYH4Ag&pw=2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(15.578003,108.471826);
        var myOptions = { 
            zoom:15, 
            center:latlng , 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }
</script>
```

How to i get a sign red "A" and a set in file HTML:

Show picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/STyUG.jpg

And what is meaning of parameter in URL Google Maps ???
Example :

> f=q;
>  source=s_q;
>  hl=vi;
>  geocode;
>  aq=0;
>   oq=7+Nguy%E1%BB%85n+Ch%C3%AD+Thanh,+T%C3%A2n+Th%E1%BA%A1nh,+Tam+K%E1%BB%B3;
>   sll=15.579176,108.470603;
>  sspn=0.001573,0.002411;
>   vpsrc=6;
>  ie=UTF8;
>   hnear=7+Nguy%E1%BB%85n+Ch%C3%AD+Thanh,+Tam+K%E1%BB%B3,+Qu%E1%BA%A3ng+Nam,+Vi%E1%BB%87t+Nam;
>   ll=15.578003,108.471826;
>  spn=0.006294,0.009645;
>  t=m;
>   z=17;
>  ei=mwSGUKXwOK2tiQeHlYH4Ag;
>  pw=2

My english is not good, and expect people to sympathize..

Answer (score 16):

Parameter             Description

`f=q`                   The f parameter, which controls the display of the Google Maps form, can                       be d (for the directions form or l for the local form). Without the f                       parameter, the default search form is displayed.

`hl=en`           Google Maps supports a limited number of host languages, including en for                       English and fr for French.

`q=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave,+Washington,+DC`
                      The value of the q parameter is treated as though it were entered via the                       query box at http://maps.google.com.

`sll=36.60585,-121.858956`
                      sll contains the latitude and longitude for the center point around which                       a business search is performed.

`spn=0.006313,0.01133`  spn is the approximate latitude/longitude span for the map.

`ie=UTF8`             ie is the character encoding for the map.

`om=1`            om determines whether to include an overview map. With `om=0` the overview                       map is closed.

`iwloc=addr`          iwloc controls display options for the info window.

A good way to get a feel for how these parameters function is to change a parameter, add new ones, or drop ones in the sample URL and take a look at the resulting map. For instance, if you have only the q parameter, you would still get a map with some default behavior:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave,+Washington,+DC
```

That is, the other parameters are not mandatory. Let’s play with the z parameter to adjust the zoom factor:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave,+Washington,+DC&z=0
```

versus the following:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave,+Washington,+DC&z=17
```

There is a comprehensive list of Google Maps parameters

- `mrad` lets you specify an additional destination address.
- `output=kml` gets a KML file to send to Google Earth.
- `layer=t` adds the traffic layer.
- `mrt=kmlkmz` shows “user-created content.” For example, the following shows user-­generated information about hotels around the White House:

  http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=hotel&near=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave,+Washington,+DC&sll=36.60585,-121.858956&sspn=0.006313,0.01133&ie=UTF8&z=16&om=1&iwloc=addr&mrt=kmlkmz

Comment: thanks Jay!
Now, I understand is this! :D
I wish you have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function initialize() {  
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(15.578003, 108.471826);  
    var myOptions = {  
      zoom: 15,  
      center: latlng,  
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
    }  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);  

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
        position: latlng,   
        map: map,  
        icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF0000|000000'  
    });     
  }  
</script>
```